# How to set images to uialertview button in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I set images to `UIAlertview` buttons without using custom buttons?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the default components.

Comment: Please try to use my code.It may help you my dear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use this one. I think it may help you..
You can do using like this without using custom button.

```
for (UIView *view in [alert subviews])
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {            
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because alert subviews are empty (before or after calling [alert show]). Any idea? iOS 9.

Comment: @HackingBear UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8, please use UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView.

Answer (score -1):

see this for uialertview button

[UIAlertview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alert)

i think this is the best [WCAlertView](https://github.com/m1entus/WCAlertView) you can change the colour

Comment: is there any possibilities to set images for alert buttons(OK and Cancel)?

Comment: see the @sunny's answer, you have to create your custom class Like  WCAlertView.h and  WCAlertView.m